# angular js empty error response

Tags: angularjs, rest

Trying to do some basic REST services from angular, but all I get back is an empty error response.

I open the index.html directly on my PC (not sure if this is the issue), and then click 'login'  which eventually calls my controller:

```
$scope.doLogin = function()
  {
   var pr = $http.get('http://localHost:7777/BuilderDBSvc/login', {params: {user: $scope.userid, pass: $scope.password} })
     .success(function(data)
      {
       console.log(data);
       domains = data;
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers, config)
      {
       console.log(data)
       console.log(status)
       console.log(headers)
       console.log(config)
      });
   pr.then(function(data)
     {
      $scope.user = data.data;
     });
  };
```

Using firefox to debug, I put breakpoints inside all 3 functions: `success` `error` and `then`.  But only 'error' is triggered. And the request always shows up in red, but with a 200 response code.  The response data shows a size of 23 bytes, but the value is always blank.

However, if I type the URL and parameters directly in my browser window, it works fine, and displays the expected json string.

Ive used this pattern before, but with nodejs and angularjs working together. but this time the REST provider is a non-java application.  I would suspect that is the problem, but when I enter the REST url directly in my browser it works fine.

What am I missing here?
Are there any better tools i can use to help debug this?

*note:

yes this is a very insecure way to do authentication, but its my starting point.*

Answer (score 0):

Is highly probable that your ploblem is by opening the index.html from your explorer because the request will not come from localhost and by that the localhost server will block the request against cross origin request in chrome console youll probably see a message saying

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load '`http://localhost:7777`'. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'your index.html location' is therefore not allowed access.

to avoid that you should make request from `http://localhost` to `http://localhost` (same server) or tell your server to accept cross origin requests

Comment: well I tried using things on a webserver (default python webserver), and using an updated version of firefox.  The problem is indeed with cross site scripting.  Since I have control over the server on port 7777, I can add the proper headers to allow CORS.  But google searching gives a lot of conflicting info... what header(s) do I need to add?

Comment: what exactly youre trying to achieve? and what errors youre getting?

Comment: by the way are you adding the ´withCredectials´ option set to true in your request??? to help you understand tour problem i think this will be usefull for your problem http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/